# How to add empty itext to canvas where i mouseclicked in fabricjs?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

I'm working on tool that make seating charts.I'm using fabricjs.i want to add itext to canvas when i clicked on canvas.That itext should be empty.Then i can type whatever i want in itext.i have no idea how to do that.need a solution.thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `enterEditing();` and `canvas.on('mouse:up', function);` for that. See my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3z44Lnxq/)

Comment: Thank you.i did see your jsFiddle.it's always add itext to the same position.but i want itext on canvas where i clicked.suppose first i click  top of the canvas,now itext should be added to that clicked position.how to do that?